# How do I make a series of variables in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iterator

I am trying to make several subsets from one Dataframe and then do the repetitive task of manipulating each subset.
for example
From existing Dataframe, df

```
for i in range(1, 101):
  globals()['df'+str(i)] = df.iloc[i:10*i, i:20*i]




df1 = df.stack()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['1'])


df2 = df.stack()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=['2'])

df3 = df.stack()
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3, columns=['3'])
.
.
.
.
df100 = df.stack()
df100 = pd.DataFrame(df3, columns=['100'])
```

After df.iloc manipulation, should I write down 100 times same code?
Is there any good way to use simple code to create 100ea sub dataframe?

Comment: don't, use a dictionary

Comment: …or a list. You don't have any meaningful names for your dfs, they're just numerical. That's a *list*.

Comment: Could you explain more detail? I cannot understand what you said. How can I use list or dictionary for my problem?

Comment: Have you seen the duplicate linked at the top?